# Create a formula to find the count in Excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I not very use to use excel complex formula.
Here is request
Column has few number (-ve/+ve). I have to count these based on intervals. These interval are not pre-decided.
See screen Shot
[image: Example]

Values in `Label col` can change in run time. A is less than -15, B is between -15 to 6 and so on. I have to create a formula to add a count in the `Count col`.

Please guide

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Have a look at COUNTIFS().

Comment: @QualiaCommunications : checked , but not very sure how to use it for my example. I am sure first one need to take the substring from label to find the value to be counted in `A`

Comment: Label column has to be parsed and to interpret the mathematical/logical conditions, Excel is not intended for that. I would suggest to formulate the conditions in a way it should be simplified to extract the conditions.

Comment: @DavidLeal : I am sure they will be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will save yourself a lot of maintenance headaches by re-formatting the "Labels" Table:

|  | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **6** |  | Greater Than or Equal To | Less Than or Equal To | Count |
| **7** | Label A | -99 | -16 | *(formula below goes here)* |
| **8** | Label B | -15 | -6 |  |
| **9** | Label C | -5 | 5 |  |
| **10** | Label D | 6 | 15 |  |

The formula to place in the first count cell (G7 in my example) is:

`=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$19,">="&E7,A$1:A$19,"<="&F7)`

And then fill it down the length of the table.  (In this example 4 rows).  Be mindful of the $ that lock the rows of your values column.

Comment: this format will be my last option.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise to follow the approach outlined by @Max as it is easier to maintain and less error-prone. However, as you stated, that you are looking for a solution that takes your format into account, I come up with this.

**Note:**
I split up the complex formula in different pieces to make it easier to explain. You can paste the different pieces together in a single cell per row if you like.

## Step 1: Getting rid of unnecessary descriptions

I use a combination of 'SUBSTITUTE', 'MID' and 'FIND' to extract our operators and values from your labels:  `F3`: `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(D3,FIND("(",D3)+1,FIND(")",D3)-FIND("(",D3)-1),"interval ","")`.
The cell `D3` contains your label, e.g. "A (interval <-15).

## Step 2: Getting the lower threshold

I check whether the label contains two thresholds or not by looking for the "/" character. Next, I handle both situations.
`G3`: `=IF(ISERR(FIND("/",F3)),MID(F3,1,LENGTH(F3)),">="&MID(F3,1,FIND("/",F3)))`
The cell `F3`contains the result of Step 1

## Step 4: Getting the upper threshold

Similar to Step 2, except for the operators.
`H3`: `=IF(ISERR(FINN("/",F3)),MID(F3,1,LENGTH(F3)),"<="&MID(F3,FIND("/",F3),LENGTH(F3)-FIND("/",F2)))`

## Step 5: Counting

I use `MID` to include the single pieces of Step 3 and Step 4 as text into the formula. If you paste everything together, the use of it will not be necessary.
`I3`: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$19,MID(G3,1,LENGTH(G3)),$A$1:$A$19,MID(H3,1,LENGTH(H3)))`

*Update*: Here's the screenshot.
[image]